# What is the difference between an inline variable assignment and a regular one in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, command-line-arguments

What is the difference between:

```
prompt$   TSAN_OPTIONS="suppressions=/somewhere/file" ./myprogram
```

and

```
prompt$   TSAN_OPTIONS="suppressions=/somewhere/file"
prompt$   ./myprogram
```

The [thread-sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/thread-sanitizer/wiki/Suppressions) library gives the first case as how to get their library (used within myprogram) to read the file given in options.  I read it, and assumed it was supposed to be two separate lines, so ran it as the second case.

The library doesn't use the file in the second case, where the environment variable and the program execution are on separate lines.

What's the difference?

Bonus question: How does the first case even run without error?  Shouldn't there have to be a ; or && between them?   The answer to this question likely answers my first...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The format `VAR=value command` sets the variable `VAR` to have the value `value` in the environment of the command `command`. The spec section covering this is the [Simple Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01). Specifically:

> Otherwise, the variable assignments shall be exported for the execution environment of the command and shall not affect the current execution environment except as a side-effect of the expansions performed in step 4.

The format `VAR=value; command` sets the shell variable `VAR` in the *current shell* and then runs `command` as a child process. The child process doesn't know anything about the variables set in the shell process.

The mechanism by which a process exports (hint hint) a variable to be seen by child processes is by setting them in its environment before running the child process. The shell built-in which does this is [`export`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_22_01). This is why you often see `export VAR=value` and `VAR=value; export VAR`.

The syntax you are discussing is a short-form for something akin to:

```
VAR=value
export VAR
command
unset -v VAR
```

only without using the current process environment at all.

Comment: Ahh, OK, thanks!  I'm confused, though, because if I do "CC=xyz" or "CXX=xyz++" without an export, cmake picks up the changes.  Shouldn't it not pick up the changes this way?  Or, when an environment variable is exported, is it being exported "by reference" rather than "by value", so perhaps a startup script exports CC and CXX without me knowing it... So if I change them, it works?

Comment: Correct, `export` marks the *variable* as exported not the current value. So you only need to export a variable once even if you change the value.

Comment: You can run `export -p` or `declare -x` to see the current list of exported variables (and their current values).

Answer (score 29):

To complement [Etan Reisner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30180289/45375):

It's **important to distinguish between *shell* variables and *environment* variables**:

<sup>Note: The following applies to *all* POSIX-compatible shells; `bash`-specific extensions are marked as such.</sup>

A ***shell* variable** is a shell-specific construct that is limited to the shell that defines it (with the exception of *subshells*, which get their own *copies* of the current shell's variables),
whereas an ***environment* variable** is inherited by *any child process* created by the current process (shell), whether that child process is itself a shell or not.
Note that [**all-uppercase variable names should only be used for *environment* variables**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

<sup>Either way, a child process only ever inherits *copies* of variables, whose modification (by the child) does *not* affect the *parent*.</sup>

- **All *environment* variables are *also* *shell* variables** (the shell ensures that),
- but the **inverse is NOT true**: ***shell* variables are NOT environment variables, *unless explicitly designated or inherited as such*** - this designation is called **exporting**.

  - note that the off-by-default `-a` shell option (set with `set -a`, or passed to the shell itself as a command-line option) can be used to *auto-export* all shell variables.

Thus,

- any variables you create *implicitly* by assignment - e.g., `TSAN_OPTIONS="suppressions=/somewhere/file"` - are ONLY shell variables, but NOT ALSO environment variables,
- EXCEPT - perhaps confusingly - *when prepended directly to a command* - e.g. `TSAN_OPTIONS="suppressions=/somewhere/file" ./myprogram` - in which case they are ONLY *environment* variables, *only in effect for THAT COMMAND*.

  - This is what Etan's answer describes.

---

Shell variables become environment variables *as well* under the following circumstances:

- based on environment variables that the shell itself inherited, such as `$HOME`
- shell variables created explicitly with `export varName[=value]` or, in `bash`, also with `declare -x varName[=value]`

  - by contrast, in `bash`, using `declare` without `-x`, or using `local` in a function, creates mere *shell* variables
- shell variables created implicitly while the off-by-default `-a` shell option is in effect (with limited exceptions)

*Once a shell variable is marked as exported* - i.e., marked as an environment variable - any *subsequent changes to the shell variable update the environment variable as well*; e.g.:

```
export TSAN_OPTIONS  # creates shell variable *and* corresponding environment variable

# ...

TSAN_OPTIONS="suppressions=/somewhere/file" # updates *both* the shell and env. var.
```

---

- `export -p` prints all environment variables
- `unset [-v] MYVAR` undefines shell variable `$MYVAR` and also removes it as an environment variable, if applicable.
- in `bash`:

  - You can "unexport" a given variable without also undefining it as a *shell* variable with `export -n MYVAR` - this removes `MYVAR` from the environment, but retains its current value as a *shell* variable.
  - `declare -p MYVAR` prints variable `$MYVAR`'s current value along with its attributes; if the output starts with `declare -x`, `$MYVAR` is exported (is an environment variable)

Comment: This answer literally answers any possible misunderstandings that someone might have.