# How to use a environment variable

Tags: python

In terminal, I set the www site and path to create a report for my tests.

I set:
`MY_URL=mysite:myport REPORTPA=./mypath/mysecondfolder/ pytest -s testFile.py --html=REPORTPA/report.html`

I should save report.html, I try a solution like:

`$REPORTPA/report.html or
%REPORTPA/report.html`

and it's not using good. How I can use my variable?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180187/setting-an-environment-variable-on-same-line-as-program-execution-is-different-t/30180842#30180842) for setting bash shell and environment vars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access environment variable values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180187/setting-an-environment-variable-on-same-line-as-program-execution-is-different-t)'s a link that might help:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `os.environ` [(docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ), like so:

```
>>> import os
>>> reportpa = os.environ['REPORTPA']
>>> print(reportpa)
./mypath/mysecondfolder/
```

Comment: Might not work if OP just does `VAR=value`, but with `export VAR=value` it should be accessible in Python.

Comment: As long as the `x=y` precedes the command and is on the same line (as it is in OP's post), the export shouldn't be necessary. Give it a try: `REPORTPA=./mypath/mysecondfolder/ python`